# Angular. Highcharts. Column Chart. Positioning of Columns on X-Axis

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I have a highchart made with Angular.JS. Each column has its own stack level and is essentially managing its own group of data

My series is an array of objects that looks like this:

```
[{
   name: seriesGroup.name,
   data: [number],
   xAxis: xAxisLevel,
   stack: xAxisLevel
}]
```

[image]

The problem I'm having is that highcharts seems to automatically add some offset styling that moves each column out of position. Ideally I want all columns centered correctly like the one for **Currency.** See image above where you can see the x-positioning that's getting added to the `rect` tag.

Is there any parameter I can set to highcharts to disable this effect? I have not been able to find anything of the sort in the API docs.

Please take a look at the fiddle for a simplified version:
https://jsfiddle.net/nz0v8w5u/

Comment: Could you prepare a simplified online example of your issue (jsfiddle)?

Comment: @WojciechChmiel sure, I just created a fiddle for it. Can you please take a look :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it setting appropriate `plotOptions.series.groupPadding` property. In your case 0.5 seems working as expected. Check the code and demo posted below.

Why do you add five xAxis instead of using just one? With one axis highcharts will automatically position columns properly and the code is much easier. Check this example: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked

**Code:**

```
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      minPointLength: 1,
      groupPadding: 0.5,
      stacking: "normal",
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      }
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7pL8mj1s/

**API reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.groupPadding

Comment: Thanks Wojciech. The reason why I have to use 5 xAxises is because each column has its own dataset and none of that data should be distributed amongst the other 4 columns. Sounds weird I know, but that's what the client wants.

Comment: Ok, I understand. If you like the answer, please upvote, thanks;)